# 'Advisors' field with variable number of names for beamer title page

Tags: beamer, titles, templates

I'd like to create a new command `\advisors{Advisor1}{Advisor2}...{AdvisorN}` (or any variation like `\advisors{Advisor1,Advisor2,...,AdvisorN}`) to be used to print inside the title of a beamer presentation a list like this

```latex
    \centering
    \textbf{Advisors:}\\
    Advisor1\\
    Advisor2\\
    ...\\
    AdvisorN
```

Here is the custom beamer template I am using for the title page

```latex
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begin{centering}
        {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}\vskip1em
        {\rmfamily\textsc{- Doctoral Disseration -}\par}\vskip1em
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{title}
            \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
            \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
            \else%
                \vskip0.25em%
                {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
            \fi%     
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \vskip1em\par
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=7pt,center]{author}
            \usebeamerfont{author}
            \textbf{PhD candidate:}\\
            \insertauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        %%% HERE SHOULD BE PRINTED THE LIST OF ADVISORS %%%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
            \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}
    \vfill
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Must it have the syntax `\advisors{Name1}{Name2}...{NameN}`? It is possible, but the more LaTeX-y way would be something like `\advisors{Name1,Name2,...}` or `\advisors{Name1\and Name2\and ...}`.

Comment: I'm fine with any syntax you can provide. Actually I know nothing about Tex/LaTex internals so feel free to suggest better options if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to define the two macros

```
\newcommand*{\@advisors}{}
\newcommand*{\advisors}[1]{\def\@advisors{#1}}
```

and to add somewhere in the title page the lines

```
\ifx\@advisors\@empty\else
\par\medskip\textbf{Advisors:}\par\def\and{\par}\@advisors
\fi
```

A full MWE, where I add the advisors in the same `beamercolorbox` containing the author.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\@advisors}{}
\newcommand*{\advisors}[1]{\def\@advisors{#1}}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begin{centering}
        {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}\vskip1em
        {\rmfamily\textsc{- Doctoral Disseration -}\par}\vskip1em
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{title}
            \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
            \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
            \else%
                \vskip0.25em%
                {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
            \fi%     
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \vskip1em\par
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=7pt,center]{author}
            \usebeamerfont{author}
            \textbf{PhD candidate:}\par
            \insertauthor
            \ifx\@advisors\@empty\else                                  % ADDED
            \par\medskip\textbf{Advisors:}\par\def\and{\par}\@advisors  % ADDED
            \fi                                                         % ADDED
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
            \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}
    \vfill
}
\makeatother

\author{Me Myself}
\title{My Work}
\advisors{First Advisor\and Second Advisor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\maketitle

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The real output of your code will of course depend on the rest of your template.